# how can i search image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

i want to search an image using UISearchBar in my app.  i had more than 100 images in tableViewController and each and every image contains name and keyword (e.g, imageName = u1-1f.png, u1-2f.png, … Keyword = Bonds, Carbohydrates).  i want to search keyword "Bonds" and it leads to u1-1f.png and so on. i am using plist and i got data from plist to array,

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"keywords" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSArray* allmyKeys = [myDictionary  allValues];
NSLog(@"%@", allmyKeys);
```

how can i search image from search bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this... Use `NSPRedicate`

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"filter string" forKey:@"email"]];  // key
NSArray *filteredarray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(email == %@)", @"filter string"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

İf you have no any special reason than i guess its better to use plist with array contents, i think you are using NSDictionary.

```
 NSMutableArray *yourArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourPlist.plist"];
NSMutableArray * plistArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
for(int key=0; key!=[plistArray count]; key++){

    [yourArray addObject:[plistArray objectAtIndex:key ]];

}
```

so you have your images in yourArray.

```
  for(int i; i!=[yourArray count]; i++)
  {
if([yourTextField.text isEqualString:[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]]){
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[yourArray objectAtIndex:i] ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
 }
}
```

You can take your image which name you've written in your textfield.

by the way i didn't check this code yet, but it will probably work.

I wish these codes will help you to solve your problem.
Good luck